# Reliable IP to Nation API

Tags: api, geolocation, ip, ip-geolocation

I was relying on YQL to do some IP to Nation transformations.  That was a mistake!

Are there any **Reliable** IP to Nation APIs out there that can be accessed via REST or something similar?

Comment: This is known as "geolocation". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geolocation+ip-geolocation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Know a good IP address Geolocation Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP function...

```
function geoip($ip = "127.0.0.1"){

    if($ip == "127.0.0.1"){$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];}//if no IP specified use your own

    $ch = curl_init();//faster than file_get_contents()
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip);//fetch data from geoplugin.net
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $curl = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $geoip = unserialize($curl);
    return $geoip["geoplugin_countryName"]." ".$geoip["geoplugin_city"];//return country and city
}
```

More info about service...
http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php